# Mule soft Custom code invoke to change HTTPSURLConnection for SSL by pass

Tags: ssl, mule, httpsurlconnection

We have self signed certificate using which mule is making HTTPS connection. In order to make it work I tried to custom bean to customize HTTPSURLConnection to not allow allHostVerification.

```
        import java.security.SecureRandom;
        import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

        import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
        import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
        import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

        import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
        import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
        import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

        public class SelfSignSSLProcessor {


        public void workAroundSelfSignedCerts() { 
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains 
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {

            new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null; 
                } 
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { } 
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { } 
            }
         };
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            System.out.println("Allow Self Signed Certificates");
            try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
            System.out.println("SSL Context Object" + sc.toString());
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom()); 
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()); 
            // Create all-trusting host name verifier

            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    System.out.println("Host Name to Verify" + hostname);
                    return true;

                }
            };
            // Install the all-trusting host verifier
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
           //  System.out.println("HTTP URL Connection for all SSL" +  HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                // do something here please! 

                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }


        }
```

I am trying to invoke this by putting invoke function right before the HTTPS call in mule flow as below.

```
             <flow name="cprimeFlow">
                    <poll doc:name="Poll">
                        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="2" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
                        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
            %output application/java
            ---
            {
            }]]></dw:set-payload>
                        </dw:transform-message>
                    </poll>
                    <invoke object-ref="SelfSignSSLProcessor" method="workAroundSelfSignedCerts" doc:name="Invoke"/>
                    <http:request config-ref="CPRIME_HTTPS" path="Devices" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
                        <http:request-builder>
                            <http:query-param paramName=".full" value="true"/>

                            <http:header headerName="Connection" value="close"/>
                            <http:header headerName="max-age" value="0"/>
                            <http:header headerName="Cache-Control" value="no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"/>
                            <http:header headerName="Expires" value="0"/>
                        </http:request-builder>
                    </http:request>
                    <logger message="CPRIME OUT Call Logs - [#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO"               doc:name="Logger"/>
                </flow>
            </mule>
```

However this does not seem to be in effect, meaning I don't think the HTTPSURLConnection in htttps connector configuration is modified for this behavior.

Let me know if I am suppose to use some other component in mule or what is the right way to put the custom HTTPSURLConnection in mule.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for the HTTP connector. If you are using Mule 3.8.0 or above you can achieve the desired outcome (no validations) by having your request configuration use a TLS context with an "insecure" trust store. You can read more about that [here](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/tls-improvements-in-mule-3-8/) (in the "Insecure option" section). HTH

Comment: I know mule 3.8 has that option. And was able to do that on 3.8, however infrastructure team is not ready for upgrade yet. Is there any way to make it work on 3.7 except setting JVM to allow any cert.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. At the time we realised you could use the system property "-Dcom.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.acceptAnyCertificate=true" to disable host name verification but not all validations. Plus that will affect all requester components in all apps.

Comment: Okay, that is not good. By the way the connector that I am using is         HTTPS   <http:request-config name="CPRIME_HTTPS"  host="xxx.xx.xx.xx" port="443" basePath="/webacs/api/v1/data/"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" tlsContext-ref="TLS">
        <http:basic-authentication username="" password=""/>
    </http:request-config>

Comment: Same connector, just different config :)

Comment: agree - I had some hope looking at this post - http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/working-with-certificates/comment-page-1/#comment-340689 but not getting the dots connected.

Comment: That post is referencing the HTTP Transport. You could try using an HTTP outbound endpoint in that case.

Comment: you mean change the HTTPS to HTTP , in that case it would ignore all the tls config right?

Comment: No, I mean that right now you are using the 3.6.0 and above HTTP Connector (configured for HTTPS connectivity). There's the deprecated HTTP/S transport from before that which is the one used in the examples of that post. Here's more on that: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/https-transport-reference

Comment: Notice how the blog post uses `<http:outbound-endpoint...` instead of `<http:request`. That's because the deprecated component is used, not the one you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding this through! I was able to achieve this by outbound-endpoint. And the funny thing I didn't have to put the custom code. It just worked as it is with "outbound-endpoint. Thanks again for  your help!